# How to avoid changing objects in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime, reference

I've got objects like:

```
DateTime a;
DateTime b;
DateTime c;
```

If I make:

```
b=a;
```

and then:

```
b=c;
```

my `a` equals `c`. 
I understand that this are dynamic objects and I've binded them with reference. But I don't want to bind them. How can I avoid this? How can I make:`b=c;`without making `a=c;` in the same time?

Comment: Actually, [`System.DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) is a structure, and thus a value type. Hence, you have *not* bound anything by reference there.

Comment: Anyway,if you're looking to do this with classes check if they have a method Clone(), look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) for more info on clone

Comment: Dynamic?? This has nothing to do with `dynamic`...!

Answer (score 3):

[`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) is a `struct` which means it's a value type.

See the following example:

```
void Main()
{
    DateTime a = new DateTime(2005, 05, 05);
    DateTime b = a;

    Console.WriteLine (a);
    Console.WriteLine (b);
    
    a = new DateTime(2012, 05, 05);
    Console.WriteLine (a);
    Console.WriteLine (b);
}
```

output:

> 5/05/2005 0:00:00
> 5/05/2005 0:00:00
>
> 5/05/2012 0:00:00
> 5/05/2005 0:00:00

Usually this can be done (in a different situation) by implementing [`ICloneable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) which defines the `Clone` method.